# Sitecore PaaS best pratice for App_Data

Tags: paas, deployment, logging, azure-devops

We are currently using Azure DevOps to deploy our Sitecore 9.1.1 and 9.2 solutions to Azure. In Azure DevOps you have the option of "leaving the App_Data" folder alone during deployment, i.e. not overwrite it. We currently use this option.

However, this also means that you will accumulate a large amount of log-files and diagnostics files over time, which as far as I understand, can slow down deployments.

Is there any Sitecore best practice in this area - should you leave the App_Data folder intact or clean it up on every deploy (assuming you include your license file and other must-have stuff in the App_Data folder, in every deploy)?

Comment: I ensure all my log files are using application insights instead. Currently looking at ways to make sure all files generated will not stay inside app_data if possible.

Comment: @VincentLui I guess you increased the max for how much data Application Insights is allowed to create then? I find that it is already difficult to use Application Insights, because there is too much data in there...

Comment: Have to use application insights if an application needs to take advantage of automatic alerts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are automatic cleanup tasks in place to deal with that.

Basically if you look under `<scheduling>` in a default `Sitecore.config`, you will find these.

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00">
  <param desc="url">/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx</param>
  <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
</agent>
<!-- Agent to process tasks from the task database (TaskDatabase) -->
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.TaskDatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:10:00" />
<!-- Agent to clean up client data -->
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CompactClientDataAgent" method="Run" interval="04:00:00" />
<!-- Agent to clean up publishing queue -->
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupPublishQueue, Sitecore.Kernel" method="Run" interval="04:00:00">
  <DaysToKeep>30</DaysToKeep>
</agent>
<!-- Agent that cleans up the event queue.
      The length of time that the EventQueue information should be kept.
      If both options are specified, IntervalToKeep is used.
      Supported options:
      DaysToKeep = The number of days that the EventQueue information should be kept. Example:<DaysToKeep>1</DaysToKeep>
      IntervalToKeep = The time in hh:mm:ss that the EventQueue information should be kept. Example: <IntervalToKeep>04:00:00</IntervalToKeep>
    -->
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupEventQueue, Sitecore.Kernel" method="Run" interval="04:00:00">
  <DaysToKeep>1</DaysToKeep>
</agent>
<!-- Agent to clear the HTML cache periodically -->
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.HtmlCacheClearAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:00" />
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.HtmlCacheClearAgent" role:require="ContentManagement">
  <patch:attribute name="interval">00:05:00</patch:attribute>
</agent>
<!-- Agent to remove expired Client authentication tickets  -->
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAuthenticationTicketsAgent" method="Run" interval="04:00:00" />
<!-- Agent to publish database periodically -->
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:00" role:require="Standalone or Reporting or ContentManagement">
  <param desc="source database">master</param>
  <param desc="target database">web</param>
  <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
  <param desc="languages">en, da</param>
</agent>
<!-- Agent to clean up work files -->
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAgent" method="Run" interval="06:00:00">
  <!-- Specifies files to be cleaned up.
          If rolling="true", [minCount] and [maxCount] will be ignored.
          [minAge] and [maxAge] must be specified as [days.]hh:mm:ss. The default value
          of [minAge] is 30 minutes.
          [strategy]: number of files within hour, day, week, month, year
          [recursive=true|false]: descend folders?
      -->
  <files hint="raw:AddCommand">
    <remove folder="$(dataFolder)/logs" pattern="*log.*.txt" maxAge="30.00:00:00" />
    <remove folder="$(dataFolder)/diagnostics" pattern="*.*" maxAge="30.00:00:00" recursive="true" />
    <remove folder="$(dataFolder)/viewstate" pattern="*.txt" maxAge="2.00:00:00" recursive="true" />
    <remove folder="$(tempFolder)/diagnostics" pattern="*.*" maxAge="00:10:00" recursive="true" />
    <remove folder="/App_Data/MediaCache" pattern="*.*" maxAge="90.00:00:00" recursive="true" />
  </files>
</agent>
<!-- Agent to dump performance counter data -->
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CounterDumpAgent" method="Run" interval="01:00:00">
  <DumpFile>$(dataFolder)/diagnostics/counters/counters.{date}.{time}.{processid}.txt</DumpFile>
</agent>
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CloneNotificationsCleanupAgent" method="Run" interval="1.00:00:00">
  <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
</agent>
```

As you can see, `App_Data` is taken care of (look for the `CleanupAgent` near the bottom). You may want to adjust some of the retention numbers, but overall the sanitising of `App_Data` is automatic.

Be aware that the `~/App_Data/DeviceDetection` is not being cleaned up by default. You may want to add that.

Source: [Cleanup Device Detection Databases](https://sitecorecorner.wordpress.com/2019/06/22/cleanup-device-detection-databases/)